# REVISED Proving $-1,1$ are branch points of $\sqrt{z^2-1}$

Tags: branch-cuts, multivalued-functions, branch-points

On some lecture notes that I am working on there is an exercise to prove that $-1,1$ are branch points of the multi-function $\sqrt{z^2-1}$.

I know that the branch $f=\sqrt{rs}e^{i\frac{1}{2}(\theta_1+\theta_2)}$, obtained by letting $z=1+re^{i\theta_1}=-1+se^{i\theta_2}$,$\theta_1,\theta_2\in (-\pi,\pi]$ encodes the the branch cut $[-1,1]$.

The notes I have, seem to imply that if we suppose $g$ is a branch on $B(1,r),r\lt1$ (open ball about $1$), then $g=\pm f$, with $f$ as above giving a contradiction.

Could an explanation be given as follows?

For a branch $g$ we can write $z=1+re^{i\phi_1+2n\pi}=-1+se^{i\phi_2+2m\pi}$ for some integers $n,m$ giving
$$g(z)=\pm \sqrt{rs}e^{\frac{1}{2}i(\phi_1+\phi_2)}e^{i\pi(n+m)}\\=\pm \sqrt{rs}e^{\frac{1}{2}i(\phi_1+\phi_2)}$$
so whether $g$ consistently takes the positive or negative root, the freedom of $n+m$ to be even or odd will add a $\pm$.

By the way the arguments are measured from the positive real axis, this is then equivalent to $\pm f$.

My feelings are that is not correct since I don’t seem to be using at any point the open ball itself.

What am I missing?

The open ball would imply that $\phi_1$ matches $\theta_1$ on the full range $(-\pi,\pi]$

Comment: Do you understand what a branch point is and how to detect it (without writing formulas)?

Comment: From what I understand $$[\sqrt{z^2-1}]=\{\lvert z-1\rvert \lvert z+1\rvert e^{i(\theta_1+\theta_2)/2}:\theta_1\in[arg(z-1)],\theta_2\in[arg(z+1)]\}$$ makes the deduction of the branch points straightforward, or equivalently we can say if any closed path around the point gives a discontinuity in argument it must be a branch point

Comment: I’ve read some others explanations in terms of singularities but that is not to be featured in these notes until further on

Comment: I should make clear the exercise is intending for the $g=\pm f$ deduction to be made to give the result

Comment: OK, so with or without your formula, what happens when you go around a little circle centered at either $z=1$ or $z=-1$? Does the function not change by a factor of $-1$? You only need to understand $\sqrt z$ as you go around a circle $|z|=\epsilon$.

Comment: It certainly does and I have proved this for $\sqrt{z}$,$\sqrt{z^2-1}$. I’m sure I can give a solution to this ignoring the hint and instead with some arbitrary $2\pi$ ranges on the arguments. What im failing to see is how we deduce that any branch on the given ball will have arguments taken from the same place

Comment: Maybe I’m being silly here but could we not take the argument to be defined from any half line starting at 0?

Comment: No, $0$ isn't relevant. You have to make cuts starting at $-1$ and $1$. There are, of course, infinitely many ways to do this, but two obvious ones are to remove $[-1,1]$ OR to remove rays from $\pm 1$ to $\infty$.

Comment: I’m with you but I’m not sure this leads me to the deduction I’m looking for. What do I need to show any branch on the ball about $1$ matches $f$ up to sign?